# Oracle 18c XE database unable to connect - IP Address changes dynamically - Error 17002

Tags: oracle, networking, connection, adapter

I have downloaded the latest Oracle SQL Developer and installed the Oracle 18c XE database . On the first day , the Oracle SQL Developer has successfully connected to XE database . But on the second day as the IP address of Wi-Fi changed the SQL developer is giving an error :

"IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Vendor code 17002".

This error is happening when ever there is a change in IP address of my Wi-Fi.

How to resolve this error permanently ? I tried updating the IP address in both tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files but it didn't worked. Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKiTq.jpg)

Comment: Don't use DHCP. Use a fixed IP address. Or if you'll only ever access locally, use localhost instead of an external IP.

Comment: I modified the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files and updated HOST = localhost , but the error remains same

Comment: You may need to tell the database to register against the new listener address too, though you'd get a different error if it didn't. (It will try to use the hostname by default.) Did you change the SQL Developer connection setting to use the same address?

Comment: May i know the steps on how to do it ?

Comment: Why do you want to stick to DHCP? Actually, if you're stuck with that, it's maybe easier to change the listener etc. to use the machine hostname instead of the IP address, since that should still then resolve - and is what the DB will use to register, so avoids having ti play with that too.

Comment: Hi , It worked now. Issue got resolved. I have provided the Host Name as my computer name. Also I have updated the HOST value in both tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files with my computer name. The connection to database has been successful and got established .

Comment: Good, glad you got it working. As this is really off-topic and a discussion in comments isn't going to help anyone else much, you could consider deleting this question. (If it was on-topic you could write up what you actually did as an answer, but it isn't, really...)

Comment: I think this is a valid question: sqldeveloper defaults to connecting to localhost, which with oracle XE 18c does not work out of the box (used to work with oracle XE 11g). So I guess this is a hurdle many eople will have to take. Changing localhost to your real computer name solved the problem for me too.